# Every sufficiently large natural number can be written as $p+n_1^2+n_2^2$ for some $n_1,n_2$ - natural numbers and $p$ - prime number

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

Every sufficiently large natural number can be written as $p+n_1^2+n_2^2$ for some $n_1,n_2$ - natural numbers and $p$ - prime number.

I saw this used in russian article, but it was given as a fact without comment.
Does this theorem have a name?

What methods are used in proofs of theorems stating that sufficiently large integers can be written in some forms?
The only somehow similar thing I know is the [Lagrange's four-square theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange's_four-square_theorem). But if we involve primes in the representation, similar methods can't work I guess

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was first proved by Hooley, assuming GRH, and later by You. V. Linnik in $1960$ without assuming the Riemann hypothesis. The proof uses non-trivial methods from analytic number theory, and the result is much more difficult than Lagrange's Theorem. There are several results "approaching the Goldbach conjecture", see for example [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.5669.pdf).